# d3 tooltip hovering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I show and hide a `tooltip` on hovering `circle`. I have a data in `tooltip` which can have a link which user probably want to click. The problem is I attached the `hover` function to the node when I try to click on `tooltip` link the `tooltip` get hide. I try to append `tooltip` inside `g` of hovering element but that did not work. Any suggestion [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnNwu/41/)

```
 nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d){ 
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "white"; 
        }).on('mouseover',function(){
            div.style('left',d3.event.pageX+20+'px').style('top',d3.event.pageY+'px').style('visibility','visible')          
        }).on('mouseout',function(){
        div.style('visibility','hidden')
        })
```

Comment: can you set a timeout in mouseout?

Answer (score 0):

Try setTimeout in mouseout event.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnNwu/42/)

```
on('mouseout',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){div.style('visibility','hidden');}, 2000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/JnNwu/43/), hiding the tooltip at specific time

```
var json = 
{
    "name": "Base",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Type A"

        },
        {
            "name": "Type B"

        }
    ]
};

var setTime;
var delayTime = 1000;
var width = 700;
var height = 650;
var maxLabel = 150;
var duration = 500;
var radius = 5;

var i = 0;
var root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

var svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ",50)");

root = json;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse);
var div= d3.select('body').append('div').attr('class','tooltip').style('visibility','hidden').html('<div class="content"><a href="http:www.google.com">google</a></div>')


function update(source) 
{
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * maxLabel; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d){ 
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i); 
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);


     nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d){ 
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "white"; 
        }).on('mouseover',function(){            
                div.style('left',d3.event.pageX+20+'px').style('top',d3.event.pageY+'px').style('visibility','visible')                     
        }).on('mouseout',function(){
        setTime = setTimeout(function() {
            div.style('visibility','hidden')
        }, delayTime);  
        })


    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){ 
            var spacing = computeRadius(d) + 5;
            return d.children || d._children ? -spacing : spacing; 
        })
        .attr("dy", "3")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 20);
    nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d){ return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}



function computeRadius(d)
{
    if(d.children || d._children) return radius + (radius * nbEndNodes(d) / 10);
    else return radius;
}

function nbEndNodes(n)
{
    nb = 0;    
    if(n.children){
        n.children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else if(n._children){
        n._children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else nb++;

    return nb;
}

function click(d)
{
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } 
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

function collapse(d){
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}
function expand(d){   
    var children = (d.children)?d.children:d._children;
    if (d._children) {        
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;       
    }
    if(children)
      children.forEach(expand);
}


 expand(root); 


update(root);
```